# Subliminal can get in a state where apps won't run

Tags: subliminal

OSX 10.9.3
xCode 5.1.1
Instruments 5.1.1
IO simulator 7.1

I am in my "Integration Tests" scheme and I launch my tests using profile.  I can do this multiple times, but eventually (almost always when there is a test error).  The tests won't launch.  I get 2 distinct failure cases:
In the first case, the login screen of my app appears in the simulator and Instrument's says the script is running, but nothing displays in the trace log.
The second case is similar to the first case except The trace log says "Test are starting up ..." but they never do.

Sometimes, stopping Instruments and running the tests again via profile causes them to run again.
Sometimes, I have to also kill the IOS simulator.
Sometimes, I have to also restart xCode.
Sometimes, I have to reboot.

It may take up to 10 attempts to get the tests to run again.

When I look at the main thread when the tests won't run, it has been sent a sigstop.

Is there deterministic way to get the tests to start running again when the system gets into this state?
Does anybody know what causes this?

(I read the known issues post "Tests occasionally fail to launch when using Xcode 5.x and/or the 6.1 Simulator and/or Mavericks" - but the proposed workaround has never worked for me)

Comment: Hi @alaursen, I'm Subliminal's maintainer. I'm sorry to hear that you're having problems launching the tests. I've never seen this issue, but I have a couple of suggestions: 1. Upgrade to OS X 10.9.4 and see if that helps at all; 2. try [running from the command line](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/wiki/Continuous-Integration#self-hosted-jenkins-or-buildbot). Does that work? (That might kickstart the GUI again too.) If not, did any errors get printed?

Comment: One more thing to try alaursen, courtesy of @jsmartin: please reset the simulator's contents and settings (from its "iOS Simulator" menu) before attempting to relaunch the tests. (It might become possible for the mechanism by which the tests and Instruments communicate, part of the app's data, to become corrupted, and a reset would fix that.) I can't tell from above if you've tried this already.

Comment: I upgraded to 10.9.4, no joy.  Where should I look for errors (there is nothing in the Instruments trace log).  Resetting the simulator's contents didn't fix the problem.

Comment: When running from the command line, errors would be printed in the Terminal. When running in the GUI, besides stuff in the trace log, is there anything interesting in Console.app?

Comment: Hi @alaursen, I just found something else that might help--when you get in a state where Instruments just won't launch, run `ps aux | grep sim` in the Terminal and then `kill -9` any processes like `launchd_sim`.